# Static pages in the subfolders of React app

Tags: reactjs, subdomain

I would like to know how I can implement static pages under the subfolders of my server side rendered React application.

Currently, I have `my-app.com` which hosts my server side rendered React app, and `blog.my-app.com` which hosts a blog powered by static pages.

But I am going to move the blog to the subfolder of the root domain: `my-app.com/blog`. I would like the blog pages to be still based on static files. What approach can I take?

Comment: I think this question is more about your server environment, not about react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your serving the app with node, using something like express (which I imagine you are if your rendering a React app server side), then you can just use the servers build in static file serving capabilities by matching the /blog route.  Here's the docs for express: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html, Hapi, Koa and all the others have similar abilities.  If you need to do some more complex route to file matching then you could use node fs to load files as strings respond with those strings.

Comment: Makes sense. Basically, do a full page load using express. Can you think of any examples of real products that are doing this (React app + static blog in the same domain)?

Comment: I'm not aware of examples where static html pages like this are served along side a react app, but I'm sure someone out there is doing it.  Just out of curiosity, how are these static blog pages generated?  By hand or from some CMS or something?

Comment: They are generated using a static site generator called Hugo.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I implemented this solution on https://remotebase.io/blog. This blog runs on static files while the main app is using React.